# Getting 307 statuscode when using POST with axios

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, axios, postman

I have a `React` application, where I use `axios` to send a post request to a `.NET Core 3.0` endpoint.

The controller method I want to hit at the route http://localhost:500/api/auth/register looks as follows:

```
    [HttpPost("register")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(UserForRegisterDto userForRegisterDto)
    {
        var userToCreate = _mapper.Map<User>(userForRegisterDto);

        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(userToCreate, userForRegisterDto.Password);

        var userToReturn = _mapper.Map<UserForDetailedDto>(userToCreate);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return CreatedAtRoute("GetUser", 
                new { controller = "Users", id = userToCreate.Id }, userToReturn);
        }

        return BadRequest(result.Errors);
    }
```

In my react frontend I send the request using axios

```
export const startLogin = (password, username) => {
    return dispatch => {
        axios
        .post(baseUrl + '/api/auth/register', {
            username,
            password
        })
        .then(data => dispatch(login(data.data.token)));
    };
};
```

But when I send the request the server responds with a 307 Temporary rediret.

[image]

The registration works fine when I issue the request using postman for some reason. Anyone know what might be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove app.UseHttpsRedirection(); in startup.cs

Comment: But isn't this a security breach?