# Axios API POST request returning a 307 redirect error even after being tested in Postman

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios, http-post

I recently moved my ReactJS app away from using the `fetch()` method for API calls and instead implemented Axios. The URL's for my API calls were all working before and were able to correctly communicate with my MongoDB database, and most of them still do when made through Axios.

My registration URL however keeps returning a `307 internal redirect` response and not posting to my database.

The registration request should return a JSON object that either contains a JWT token or "NA" depending on whether or not the user already exists in the database. When tested through Postman this POST request returns correctly in both cases.

However when making an indentical call through my ReactJS frontend a blank response with no data is sent back along with the aforementioned `307 internal redirect` code.

The URL I am currently using for users to register is
`http://localhost:3000/register/username/password/ID_number/mobile_number/email/accountnum/college/degree/date/location`

[The response and URL in Google Chrome dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u24Kf.png)

The current code for making the API request from the front end.

```
await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/register/'+this.name+'/'+this.password+'/'+this.ID+'/'+this.phoneNum+'/'+this.email+'/'+this.accountNum+'/'+this.university+'/'+this.courseName+'/'+this.dateOfBirth+'/'+this.area, {})
.then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
})
```

From testing I know that both the URL itself and my backend controller method to handle the registration are working correctly as they both work in isolation. The issue only arises when I try send the same request from my frontend.

Any ideas as to what could be causing this would be greatly appreciated. I can provide any additional info if need be.

Comment: According to my understanding, this won't create a much problem. But, still you can reference similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59117365/getting-307-statuscode-when-using-post-with-axios

Comment: @MaulikPatel Thank you for your response. I have already looked at that article unfortunately and the only listed solution there relates to a file that is specific to .NET projects

Comment: I think this is something related to cors origin policy.